# Send mail with attachment using mailjet in GAS

Tags: email, google-apps-script, email-attachments

I am trying to send mail with a PDF attachment using Mailjet from Google Apps Script. I can send regular mail without issue, but not quite sure how to include an attachment.

Mailjet documentation: https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#sending-with-attached-files

I think my problem is the Base64Content. I don't really understand how to encode the attachment. When I execute the below code, an email is being sent with a PDF attachment, but when I try and open the PDF it displays: "Cannot display PDF (test.pdf is of invalid format)".

```
var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocid)

var attachment = newDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

var mailjeturl = "https://api.mailjet.com/v3.1/send";

var mailjetparams = {
    "Messages":[{
      "From": {"Email": 'myemail@domain.com',"Name": 'Robert'},
      "To": [{"Email": 'theiremail@domain.com'}],
      "Subject": 'subject',
      "HTMLPart": 'this message',
      "Attachments": [{"ContentType": "application/pdf",
                       "Filename": "test.pdf",
                       "Base64Content": Utilities.base64Encode(attachment)}]
    }]
  }

var mailjetoptions = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(mailjetparams),
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(MAILJET_KEY)}
  };

var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(mailjeturl, mailjetoptions))
```

Comment: Is it compulsory to use Mailjet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modification? I thought that the reason of the error may be `Utilities.base64Encode(attachment)`.

#### Modification points :

`attachment` retrieved by `newDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF)` is Blob. The Blob cannot be directly converted to base64 using `Utilities.base64Encode()`. So please convert Blob to byte array, and convert to base64.

When this is reflected to your script. The modification part is as follows.

#### From :

```
var attachment = newDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
```

#### To :

```
var attachment = newDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF).getBytes();
```

or

```
var attachment = newDoc.getBlob().getBytes();
```

When Google Document is retrieved as a Blob, Google converts automatically to PDF. You can also use this.

#### Reference :

- [base64Encode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode(Byte))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Robert Welcome. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to encode like this:

```
  var pdf = newDoc.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'test.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  var mailjetparams = {
    "Messages":[{
    "From": {"Email": 'sender@domain.com',"Name": 'Robert'},
    "To": [{"Email": 'reciever@domain.com'}],
    "Subject": 'subject',
    "HTMLPart": 'this message',
    "Attachments": [attach]
   }]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @iJay. Really appreciate the help.